# i get an error for the following comand 'sudo mysql_secure_installation' ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, shell, installation

after installing mysql and went to secure the Mysql
every time i set in a new password it still gives me to set a new password:
I indicate I would like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin when I'm asked. Then I am running into this endless loop, even my password strength is 100

```
**Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.
The 'validate_password' component is installed on the server.
The subsequent steps will run with the existing configuration
of the component.
Please set the password for root here.

New password: 

Re-enter new password: 

Estimated strength of the password: 100
Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : Y
 ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.

New password:**
```

i went for STRONG password
i followed the steps on digital ocean
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04

```
**There are three levels of password validation policy:

LOW    Length >= 8
MEDIUM Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, and special characters
STRONG Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, special characters and dictionary    
Please enter 0 = LOW, 1 = MEDIUM and 2 = STRONG:**
```

Comment: you link also provides an answer for that, is something unclear about the alter command for the user in the text ?

Comment: yes when i run 
**ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';**
nothing happens

Comment: have you tried to use the `pasword as pasword`for root?

Comment: no i didn't try that, 
do you mean if have set the same password as the root
if so no. I used a password containing mixed case, int and special char
if it's not what you meant tell me more.

Comment: you have password as loginpassword for user root in your command, what i meant, is if you tried the password that you used in the ALTER command after exiting the mysql command shell

Comment: aw i didn't, i feel dumb, you solved my problem thank you.